# macos swiftUI send simulator keyboard event

Tags: macos, cocoa, swiftui

Everybody:

I just dev a macOS desktop app, I create one button then clicked for simulator the keyborad event send some char such as `a` to the textfield above, but not working. Any help?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var username: String = ""
    @FocusState private var emailFieldIsFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField(
                    "User name (email address)",
                    text: $username
                )
                .focused($emailFieldIsFocused)
                .onSubmit {
                    
                }
                .disableAutocorrection(true)
                .border(.secondary)
            Button {
                print("button clicked")
                let src = CGEventSource(stateID: CGEventSourceStateID.hidSystemState)

                let eventDown = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: UInt16(0), keyDown: true)
                eventDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
                
                let eventUp = CGEvent(keyboardEventSource: src, virtualKey: UInt16(0), keyDown: false)
                eventUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
                
                
            } label: {
                Text("click me")
            }.padding()
        }
        
    }
```

I hope simulate the keyboard input `a` to the textfield then click the button, but nothing to send.

[the app ui img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ovm3M.png)